# How to overcome supervisor who is interested in pushing their own research ideas independent of original advertised PhD project?

Tags: phd, advisor

I have been undertaking a PhD for three months. I have two supervisors, one is easy to get hold of, the other one isn't.

I presumed that when starting this three months ago, a clear initial starting research question would have been devised based on the data available, and that this complete dataset would be readily accessible.

However, upon starting, it seems this is not the case. There is only a partial dataset available, which limits what can be explored. In addition to this, one supervisor is extremely keen on pushing  analyses/research topic that is completely different to what was advertised in the PhD project, which align with his interest/expertise and not mine. I would not have applied for a project based on this, and there was no chance this would have arisen given the initial PhD project description and following discussions.

Please could anybody advise or comment if they have had previous experiences. I would like to be able to direct the research and carry out analyses based on my original interests and the PhD project that was advertised, but am uncertain how this will influence my working relationship with this supervisor, if I decline to carry out the analyses they want me to carry out in a different topic.

Thanks

Comment: The only possible answer is to talk to your supervisors. They will either address your concerns, or not. After that you can decide what to do with that.

Comment: Research directions change and evolve over time. Yours will as well. How different, really, is the new path?

Comment: It is natural to stick close to one's background.  However, doing so means you won't grow.  Your co-supervisor may have the same mindset.

Answer (score 4):

Your assumption that the data was already available was unusual and incorrect. Having a completely well formed research question is also a bit unusual. "Look at this..." is about as much as many students get.

Most  people who are successful in getting a doctorate have interests that align with those of their supervisor(s). There are exceptions, but it depends on a hands-off advisor willing to approve work that has little specific interest for them and a highly skilled and motivated student. This happens, but it isn't the norm.

If you don't align with your supervisors and can't do it all alone, then you need to find other supervisors or even change programs. I think your expectations were unreasonable, but you are lucky to learn of the issues only a few months in.

Maybe you can carry out the original research largely alone. But don't wind up fighting with one of your supervisors as that is likely to have a poor outcome,

Comment: '"Look at this..." is about as much as many students get.' That strongly depends on the research field. In my field, funding proposals need a detailed research question and quite detailed work plans. PhD students usually are than hired for the resulting project and thus have a clear work plan.

Comment: @Roland, yes, lots of things are field dependent. I worry, though that some will think that getting a doctorate and doing research is a largely mechanical process.

Answer (score 0):

Ask for a formal meeting, ie, scheduled time and an agenda, with both advisors to discuss what you anticipated, what you found, and whether your prior expectations were appropriate.

Plan for this meeting by obtaining any relevant documents covering the project, that is, proposals, approvals from committees such as human subjects or animal subjects, and review and approvals at higher levels, such as a department head or dean. Obtain any approvals from a funding agency.

Review these documents. Projects should do what they promise and plan, within reason.

If your own plans and expectations are consistent with these documents then describe what is in the documents and what you plan to do to both you advisors at the same time.

If your own plans are not consistent with the documentation then you are mistaken and must recognize this. If your advisors' plans are not consistent with the documentation, then they are likely in trouble. If so, one or both will back down.

If none of this works, ask to meet with the department head, graduate program director, or dean with your advisors and lay it all out for that person.

You are entitled to a businesslike approach to your project from everyone. Everyone is required to follow the procedures of your university. The administration knows this well, is aware that if they don't, you can sue them, and, if they don't follow procedures they will lose, you will win, and they will have to patch everything up in your favor. About the time you ask to meet with a dean, you will know either that you are wrong or they will give in.

If none of this works, leave and go somewhere else where you can get something done. It isn't worth suing them. You don't want to be around them.

You might want to find out the name of an appropriate attorney and meet with them for 1-2 hours. Most universities are plagued by attorneys who specialize in suing them.